# How can I send cloudant db data to ejs template from an app.js file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, cloudant, nano

I'm new with nodejs, I need some help. I've app.js file, where I make a query to a cloudantDB using nano driver, the code looks like this:

```
var nano = require('nano')('localhost:3000'),
db   = nano.use('compania_cia')
result = ";

db.get('compania_cia', function(err, body) {
    if (!err) {
      result = body;

    }
});
```

I tried send "result" to a contact view of this way:

```
app.get('/contact', function(req, res) {


    res.render('contact', { ct: req._csrfToken,result:result});
});
```

But , when I run my application I get error 500.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your error description isn't really helpful because there are many reasons why a web server might return HTTP status code 500. Have you inspected the server log? It should contain the information you need. Glancing at your couchdb/Cloudant specific code snippet there are several problems. Save that code into a file and try to run it locally (`node blah.js`). You should be able to quickly identify and resolve the problems if you

- Verify that you have the `nano` package specified as a dependency in `package.json` (and installed it locally `npm install nano` for this test)
- Make sure your database URL format and value is correct
- Verify that there are no syntax errors in your code

All of the issues listed are fatal and could lead to the internal server error you are getting. A corrected version of your code might look as follows:

```
 var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984'),
 db = nano.use('mydatabase'),
 result = '';

 db.get('mydocumentid', function(err, body) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));   
  } 
  else {
    console.log('Body: ' + JSON.stringify(body));
  }
 });
```

Comment: Hi @ptitzler, I ran a blah.js file, and I can obtain response with the json structure of my cloudantdb's table, but my really problem is how can I send this response to a ejs view.

Comment: When I execute on my browser localhost:3000/contact, I just can to see Internal Server Error. So , I tried to put the code that calls to db into app.get('/contact', function(req, res)...but I get the same error...thanks a lot..

Comment: Sorry, unless you can produce more details (like an error message on the server) there's nothing I can do to help. Based on what you've shared thus far the issue doesn't seem to be caused by the database.